# ImageJ cannot find symbol

Tags: imagej, cannot-find-symbol

So I have no idea why I get a "cannot find symbol error" for img in the following code. This code is based off an ImageJ Plugin template that works perfectly fine, so something must be eluding me...

```
    import ij.*;
    import ij.process.*;
    import ij.plugin.filter.*;
    public class Plug2 implements PlugInFilter 
    {

           public int setup(String arg, ImagePlus imp)
           {
               return DOES_RGB;
           }

          public void run(ImageProcessor img)
          {
               int i, j, swap;
               for (j = 0; j < img.getLength(); j++)
                   for (i= 0; i < img.getWidth(); i++)
                   {
                         swap = img.getPixel(i, j);
                         img.setPixel(i, j, img.getPixel(img.getWidth()-i, j));
                         img.setPixel(img.getWidth()-i, j, swap);
                   }
          }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Answer (score 0):

The [ImageProcessor](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/ij/process/ImageProcessor.html) class does not have methods `setPixel` or `getLength`, thus the [Cannot find symbol error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean).

I assume you want [putPixel](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/process/ImageProcessor.html#putPixel-int-int-int-) or [set](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/process/ImageProcessor.html#set-int-int-int-), and  [getWidth](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/process/ImageProcessor.html#getWidth--)